# Python program that allows user to restart or exit it

Tags: python

I want this program to allow users to restart the game when they are through or exit it if they do not want to play the game again, but I cant figure out how to do it. Can you please help me with the code that makes the program do that?
Please correct me if I mistype the code below.
Below is the code of the game I have written using python:

```
import random

secret_number = random.randrange(1, 101)

guess = 0
tries = 0

while guess != secret_number:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
    tries = tries + 1

    if guess < secret_number:
        print("Too low!")

    elif guess > secret_number:
        print("Too high!")

    else:
        print("You got it!")
        print("Number of tries: ", tries)

    userInput = input("Enter 'R' to restart or 'X' to exit").capitalize()

    if userInput == "R":
        #code to restart the game goes here

    elif gameReply == "X":
        #code to exit the game goes here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your indentation was wrong.
2. You can try to use a smaller `random.randrange()` while you are **testing** your program.
3. After the game finishes, what do you want to do if user inputs, say, `hello`? In the following program, you basically continue if it is not `x` or `X` and play again.

Here is the fixed version:

```
import random
import sys

while True: # outer game loop

    print('Welcome to the game.')

    secret_number = random.randrange(1, 5)

    guess = 0
    tries = 0

    while guess != secret_number:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
        tries = tries + 1

        if guess < secret_number:
            print("Too low!")

        elif guess > secret_number:
            print("Too high!")

        else:
            print("You got it!")
            print("Number of tries: ", tries)

    userInput = input("Enter 'R' to restart or 'X' to exit").capitalize()

    if userInput == "X":
        print('Goodbye.')
        sys.exit(-1) # exits the program
```

Comment: I admire your code and i tried it out and it did work perfectly, but there are few things that I don't understand: 1. is your imported a module called "sys"; what is that module used for? 2. The outer loop you are using seems cool, but I don't understand what is going on there, and why is the statement saying "While True:". 3. At the end of the program you use this code "sys.exit(-1)" now, I understand that code should exit the program but why does it have a parameter of (-1). I'll will be glad if you gave me an understanding of what I don't understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NathanSiafa You are welcome. 1. [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#module-sys) is a module for system-specific parameters and functions. 2. Outer loop is the so called game loop, please see [this post](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/tips-for-writing-the-main-game-loop). 3. Actually I realize now using [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) (without -1) would be a better idea here. The parameter you give to the `sys.exit()` is basically for debugging purposes and such.

Answer (score 0):

To restart the game: Well, you can declare a function that initializes the game, and then you call it if you want to restart.

To exit:

sys.exit()

I have a similar game already coded: you can have a look at it [HERE](https://gist.github.com/ArielAleksandrus/9dd5da003162e7f177c3). It was my first python code

Answer (score 0):

For restart, you can just set tries to zero and `continue` since you are in a loop.

```
if userInput == "R":
    tries = 0
    continue
```

For exit, `sys.exit()` is a winner.

```
elif gameReply == "X":
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Got logic but with that the player is only allow to guess once

Answer (score -1):

You can use sys.exit() to stop the script and wrap your code into a method so you can call it again when the user wants to restart.  Also, use raw_input rather than input as input is expecting Python code.

For example:

```
import random
import sys

def my_game():
    secret_number = random.randrange(1, 101)

    guess = 0
    tries = 0

    while guess != secret_number:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
        tries = tries + 1

        if guess < secret_number:
            print("Too low!")

        elif guess > secret_number:
            print("Too high!")

        else:
            print("You got it!")
            print("Number of tries: ", tries)

        userInput = raw_input("Enter 'R' to restart or 'X' to exit").capitalize()

        if userInput == "R":
            my_game()

        elif userInput == "X":
            sys.exit()

my_game()
```

Comment: The indentation is wrong here, because print says "number of tries", which does not make sense in this version.

Comment: @Sait Please correct me - where is indentation wrong?  Number of tries is reset at each time the user enters 'R' and is incremented at each loop.